# Group Action and Smooth Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I was wondering if it is sufficient for a compact (i.e. Hausdorff) smooth manifold  $M$ to have a free group action of a finite group $G$ in order to conclude that $M/G$ is a compact smooth manifold?

This is definitely wrong if $M$ is not compact, but I suspect that it might be true for such manifolds.

Comment: @PeterFranek: Is that action free...? (The origin/center seems to be fixed by every group element.)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_action) seems to say that this is the case, and that it is a consequence of the [slice theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_theorem_(differential_geometry)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for finite $G$, $M/G$ is a smooth manifold, regardless of any compactness assumptions. For a general discrete group $G$ acting on a manifold $M$, you need the action to be free and *properly discontinuous* in order to make $M/G$ into a smooth manifold (and $M\to M/G$ into a covering). The second condition means that for each $x\in M$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ such that $gU\cap U\neq\emptyset$ is only possible for $g=e$. This means that the projection $M\to M/G$ restricts to a homoemorphism on $U$ and you can use this to construct charts on $M/G$. For a finite group $G$ this condition is always satisfied, an appropriate neighbourhood is easily constructed using that $M$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: This definition only "works" for (meaning that it can only ever be satisfied by) discrete groups. The map $G \times M \to M \times M$, $(g,x) \mapsto (x, g \cdot x)$ is continuous, so the preimage of $U \times U$ is open; in particular since $G$ isn't discrete, it contains at least one $(g, y)$ with $g \neq e$, ie. $(y, g \cdot y) \in U^2 \implies y \in gU \cap U$. For a nondiscrete group you want a *proper action*, meaning the aforementioned map $G \times M \to M \times M$ is proper (this implies the quotient is Hausdorff).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I completely agree, I was only talking about discrete groups in my reply. I have sligthly edited the reply in order to clarify.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The compactness assumption in the question was on $M$, not on $G$.

Comment: Oh right :/ my bad.